# Using objects in an NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview

Hey I have these UIView objects in a dictionary I have created as such:

```
- (NSArray *)createNumberOfViews:(NSInteger)number
{
NSMutableArray *viewArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSInteger i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    // any setup you want to do would go here, e.g.:
    // view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [viewArray addObject:view];
    [view release];
}
return viewArray;
}
```

So now I need to access each member of this array and add them each to a superview, any ideas how i might go ahead and do this?

Comment: A quick glance at the documentation for NSArray (and UIView if necessary) will show you the way

Comment: It is really a matter of style/preference, but unless the returned array will be modified, you should return an immutable array.. `return [NSArray arrayWithArray:viewArray];`. Otherwise you should change your method declaration to return `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: @ohhorob: That really is a matter of preference. The fact that his array is an NSMutableArray is an implementation detail, just like the fact that all NSArrays are actually NSMutableArrays (seriously, check `[[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Hello"] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]`). His method signature is accurate and his method implementation is efficient, so there's really no need to complicate things or expose private implementation details IMO.

Comment: I think I was pretty clear that my comment *"is really a matter of style/preference"*! Personally, my reasoning of why the declaration should "declare" (yes, really!) the actual return type of a mutable/immutable class cluster is it can provide semantics useful to reading and using the code. At the end of the day it's not a big deal, but a useful habit nonetheless.

Answer (score 6):

Just get the result of that method and [enumerate through it](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocFastEnumeration.html):

```
for (UIView *view in [self createNumberOfViews:42]) {
    [yourSuperview addSubview:view];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `NSArray *views = [self createNumberOfViews:10]` then use

```
[(UIView *) addSubview[views objectAtIndex:number]];
```

That should work. Comment if it doesn't, but this is pretty basic.
Edit: Oops. Didn't quite understand. Fixed up code :P

Comment: Not quite. @Ollie asks about adding each view in the array to a superview; you are adding subviews to each view in the array

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
for(NSInteger i = 0; i < [viewArray count]; i++)
{
     UIView *view = (UiView*)[viewArray objectAtIndex:i];
     [parentView addObject:view];   // parentView = your super view
}
```